# What is the highest Ruby version supported by Rails v4.1.16?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In other words, can I run Rails 4.1.16 on Ruby 2.4? If not, can I run it on Ruby 2.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [CI settings](https://travis-ci.org/rails/rails/builds/144346823) for `4-1-stable`, I'd say stick with Ruby 2.3. `2.4.0` isn't on that list, as things stand.

That's not to say that `4.1.16` won't run on Ruby 2.4 - I can't really speak to that - but there's always a possibility that you hit subtle issues, depending on the features you use and the gems that you include. Ruby 2.4 has the `Fixnum` and `Bignum` unification, as well as unicode changes - which potentially could have an impact.

FWIW, we have a sizeable, battle-tested application on the `4.1.x` branch that works just fine on Ruby 2.3.3.

Comment: Thanks! I suspect there might be a reason `4-1-stable` is not tested with 2.4.0 on CI.

Answer (score 0):

seems 2.4 should work with rails 4.x

> Rails generally stays close to the latest released Ruby version when
> it's released:
>
> ```
> .... 
> Rails 4 prefers Ruby 2.0 and requires 1.9.3 or newer.
> ...
> ```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#ruby-versions

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/4.1.16), Rails 4.1.16 should work with any  ruby version higher or equal to 1.9.3. I would recommend testing it extensively in a local environment so you can check for any possible deprecations.
 Also, in case you are not, consider using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or any other Ruby version manager.

The [Rails blog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2017/2/21/Rails-4-2-8-has-been-released/) posted recently that the first version of the 4.2 series that officially support Ruby 2.4 is Rails 4.2.8.